# "общение" со строкой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Допустим есть банальная таблица

**`| id | Name | Pass |`**
`|  1 | Oleg | 1234 |`
`|  2 | Petr | 1124 |`
`|  3 | Anna | 2222 |`

Какой должен быть запрос, чтобы:

- Получить по `'Name'` и `'Pass'` получить `'id'`
- Получить все значения по `'id'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю каким расширением вы ползуетесь, поэтому пишу в общем, используя неименованные  плейсхолдеры для [подготавливаемых запросов](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
# получить id по Name и Pass
SELECT `id` FROM `table_name` WHERE `Name` = ? AND `Pass` = ?

# получить все данные по id
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = ?
```

Comment: `SELECT *` может быть как числом, так и определённым значением?

Comment: `SELECT *` говорит о том, что будут выбраны все поля таблицы. А при чем тут "число", я что-то не понял